# Why on some lists i can do item-level edit while on others i can not

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience

I am working on custom lists inside 2 site collections on the same tenant. On the first site >> when i click on a list item >> a popup will open >>where i can do an item level edit without clicking on the "Edit all" link, as follow (where i can edit the title):-
[image]

While on the second site >> the item level seems disabled and to edit the item i need to click on the "Edit all" link:-
[image]

so can anyone advice why we get different behaviors on different sites? is this a feature that is not rolled out for all sites? or there is a setting which we can control this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is controlled in list settings-> Advanced Settings-> Quick property editing:

[image]

If you choose yes,  we can edit directly without clicking on the "Edit all" link

Comment: yes i tried to disable the quick edit >> but still users can edit all the multiple line of text fields... did you try at your end?

Comment: Per my test, only multiple line of text field that enable append changes to existing text can be edited. You could click edit columns in the detail pane to make multiple line of text field hidden in the pane.

Comment: This seems fixed by Microsoft, the multiple line of text fields cannot be edited.  But the edit button still exists for the multiple line of text fields

Comment: i tested this at my end and i still can edit multiple line of text fields

Comment: in my case if i hide the column from the pane it will also hide it from the edit form when rendered in classic mode,,, which will not work for me, as i rely on the edit form in classic UI to do the edit for all the fields..